# Azure Maps cache in flask

Tags: javascript, flask, azure-maps

I'm using azure maps for data visualization in the Flask application. I have a lot of data so sometimes my browser crash or becomes very slow.
Is there any way I can implement cache or some other things to speed up browser?
My data is refreshed after every 15 minutes.
Looking for help.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some different approaches you can take. Local cache is one approach, but only really works if the user will only be viewing a subset of the data at a time. That said, this requires a lot of work and is likely to give the least benefit.

A more common approach is to improve the data format you are using with the map. Instead of sending the raw data to the map consider doing one of the following:

1. Only send the geometry data and the minimum data needed to render it, plus a unique ID. Then, if you need additional information, query a backend system using the ID when needed. This can often significantly decrease the memory footprint of an app.
2. Consider serving your data as vector tiles. This is a great way to serve massive datasets to the map (the base maps which has hundreds of billions of geometries are served like this). If you have a lot of metadata for geometries, like long descriptions, it is best to separate those out and store those in a database that you can retrieve when needed using a unique ID.